# get ROW number in a user defined formula in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Im trying to create a formula that will populate a cell based on the row the formula is entered in without having to populate another cell separately to hold the row number;
Here is an example google apps script (not working) which is intended to produce an array of the row number and then that number doubled and then trebled;

```
function DOUBTREB() {

  var input = Row();

  var dub = input*2;
  var treb = input*3;
  return [[input, dub, treb]];
};
```

Sheets throws an an error that Row is not defined.
How do I go about getting it to work?

Comment: Please consider improve your answer to comply with these guidelines: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the row number. Try this:

```
function doubtreb(){
 var input=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getRow() 
 var dub = input*2;
 var treb = input*3;
 return [[input, dub, treb]];
}
```